# run command on each line in a file?

Tags: bash, scripting

using this tool, https://github.com/maurosoria/dirsearch,

I need to somehow write a bash one liner which allows me to take a big domain list in and run ./dirsearch.py on each domain in the file and then output the status codes which result in 200.

I assume i need to use xargs to do this.

Something like cat  | xargs -n1 -P1 -I+ ./dirsearch.py. I'm not very familiar with xargs and the flags so I am curious on how to do this.

I also would like a detailed explanation if possible on what flags exactly work and why they do so.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As you mentioned, xargs can help you.
-L option will help you to use xargs on each line
-P option will help you to run xargs on multiple processes

```
cat yourdomainlist | xargs -L1 -P8 python dirsearch.py $1
```

Well -L option sets the number of lines read before executing the python process. 
-P sets the number of processes.

For example I will create a file test.txt containing

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

And a script test.sh containing

```
echo $@
```

This command :

```
cat test.txt | xargs sh test.sh
```

will return

```
hello test1 test2 test3 test4
```

This command :

```
cat test.txt | xargs -L 2 sh test.sh
```

will return

```
hello test1 test2
hello test3 test4
```

And this :

```
cat test.txt | xargs -L 1 sh test.sh
```

will return

```
hello test1
hello test2
hello test3
hello test4
```

---

Now we verify the -P parameter :

I edit my test.sh file to add a sleep parameter :

```
sleep 10   
echo $@

cat test.txt | time xargs -L 1 -P 1 sh test.sh
```

will return

```
hello test1
hello test2
hello test3
hello test4
0.00user 0.00system 0:40.01elapsed
```

and this :

```
cat test.txt | time xargs -L 1 -P 4 sh test.sh
```

returns

```
hello test3
hello test1
hello test2
hello test4
0.00user 0.00system 0:10.00elapsed
```

Comment: how would i add threads without using the dirsearch --t option?, is there a equivalent to -P1 with awk?

Comment: Edited with a xargs solution